# Wrap all next_elements in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a piece of HTML like so:

```
<figure>
    <img src=".." alt=".." />
    Some text that I have to wrap in <code>figcaption</code>
</figure>
```

And I am trying to wrap everything that follows `<img>` in a `<figcaption>`. Is that possible?

`next_elements` works fine to get the elements I want, but returns a generator, which doesn't play nicely with the `wrap` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <figure>
...     <img src=".." alt=".." />
...     Some text that I have to wrap in <code>figcaption</code>
... </figure>
... """)
>>> for figure in soup.find_all("figure"):
...     img = figure.find("img")
...     if img is not None:
...         figcaption = soup.new_tag("figcaption")
...         for el in list(img.next_siblings):
...             figcaption.append(el)
...         img.insert_after(figcaption)
... 
>>> soup
<html><body><figure>
    <img alt=".." src=".."/><figcaption>
    Some text that I have to wrap in <code>figcaption</code>
</figcaption></figure></body></html>
```

A few things to note:

1. We use [`next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings), which returns only the elements we actually need, rather than [`next_elements`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-elements-and-previous-elements), which would continue past the end of the `figure` element.
2. We wrap `next_siblings` with `list()` to create a shallow copy we can iterate over - otherwise, since the act of appending `el` to `figcaption` removes it from its former position in the document tree, that would modify the sequence we'd be iterating over, which is [a bad idea](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/). We could have used [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) (which also returns a list) instead, but the version above is more explicit.
3. Since we *have* removed all the next-siblings of `img` from their former place in the document tree, all we then need to do is append `figcaption` (which now contains them) immediately after the `img` element.
4. The placement of whitespace is no longer intuitively "right" to a human being, but fixing that would require significant extra work, and probably isn't worth it.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Jinja2 generated this HTML so my whitespace is all over the place anyway.